# Android image filter libraries

Tags: android, graphics, image-processing, filter, image-manipulation

Are there any image libraries available for Android as seen in http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html? Or have some one ported the same? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old topic, but in the absence of the AWT libraries I have started porting some [image filters](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/plugins.html) from the Marvin Image framework ([found here](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/index.html))

I have set it up as a [googlecode project here](http://code.google.com/p/android-image-filtering/) so feel free to go check it out.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a very elaborate set of them, but the [graphics class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary.html) contains a number of methods that are useful for some types of these operations.

For example, using the color matrix you could perform a convolution on an image.  Depending on what you want to do, you may have what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Samsung S Pen SDK Has image filters. The filters are implemented for ARM devices. Here's a link: [S Pen SDK](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=11924&nacode=uk). Works fine for any Android devices with or without S Pen.

Comment: Hey I already used this sdk in my project. But i had a doubt. I think, it only work with samsung devices. I tried to install my app (which is created using spen sdk) in kindle fire, filter are not applied. Do you know what is reason for this? Is this SDK work on all ARM devices?.