# Library for Image Filters In Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android image filter libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280162/android-image-filter-libraries)

Can Anyone provide me the library file to filter image in Android like Black & White, Sepia,vintage, polaroid etc....

Answer (score 6):

Please do Googling first.
Anyway, you can follow my series on Android Image Processing to make a start:
http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/

Comment: I guess google took me here :b